# magento 1.8 bundle product get 2 highest product price

Tags: magento-1.8, price, bundled-product

I am trying to create a bundle product here i just show `final price` as highest 2 product `prices`.

**For example**

1. Product-1 price Rs. 100
2. Product-2 price Rs. 200
3. Product-3 price Rs. 300

Final price is Rs. 500

For the above  final price = (Product-2 + Product-3) as Rs. 500 /-

How can i show that in `bundle products` `view` & `list` pages.

Thanks in advance...!